# The annotation 'xy' conflicts with a field on the model - django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have models:

```
class Topiccenter(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  def sumentries(self):
    return self.tc_books.count() + self.tc_journals.count()

class Book(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  tc = models.ForeignKey(Topiccenter,related_name="tc_books")

class Journal(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  tc = models.ForeignKey(Topiccenter,related_name="tc_journals")
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
Topiccenter.objects.annotate(tc_books=Sum('tc_books'),
                              journals=Sum('tc_journals')
                              ).extra(
                                   select={'sum_entries':'tc_books+journals'}, 
                                   order_by=('sum_entries',)
                              )
```

but it is saying: `The annotation 'tc_books' conflicts with a field on the model.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `tc_books` is also the related name for your books. Also, you're trying to use `Sum` on a non-numerical value. You should use `Count` instead. Try this:

```
Topiccenter.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('tc_books'),
                             num_journals=Count('tc_journals')
                             ).extra(
                                 select={'sum_entries':'num_books+num_journals'}, 
                                 order_by=('sum_entries',)
                             )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
topics = Topiccenter.objects.all()
topics_by_count = []
for topic in topics:
   books = topic.book_set.count()
   journals = topic.journal_set.count()
   print('Number of books: {}'.format(books))
   print('Number of journals: {}'.format(journals))
   print('Total Entries: {}'.format(books+journals))
   topics_by_count.append((books+journals, topic,))

topics_sorted = sorted(topics_by_entries, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
for count, topic in topics_sorted:
   print('{}: {}'.format(topic, count))
```

Comment: thanks. shorter way would be ``books=Sum('tc_books')``, but this is not working saying: ``Column »books« does not exist``. do you know why?

Comment: You need to use the related name, so `books` should be `tc_books` etc.

Comment: now it is saying: ``The annotation 'tc_books' conflicts with a field on the model.``

Comment: What is the exact query you are running?

Comment: Note that without `prefetch_related('book_set', 'journal_set')`, this will use 2 database query for every topiccenter. Even with `prefetch_related`, it will execute 3 queries where only 1 is needed.